# Is there any way to connect a GAE application with a custom Google Cloud Database?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, webapp2

I'm trying to connect my webapp2 application to a 'in-cloud' database.
To run it local I'm using the following commands:

```
 --datastore_path=/<path>/<to>/<project>/.db/datastore
 --blobstore_path=/<path>/<to>/<project>/.db/blobstore
```

The problem is that I don't want a local path to my datastore/blobstore.
Is there any way to connect in a 'in-cloud' database passing a different path? Can't find any solutions like that

Comment: Can you please specify which database you'd like to use and what exactly you mean by `in-cloud` database?

Comment: I'm trying to get a remote access to Google Cloud Datastore using webapp2.

Comment: Your webapp2 could access the Datastore using the [Remote API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/remoteapi).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Remote API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/remoteapi):

> The Remote API library allows any Python client to access services
> available to App Engine applications.
>
> For example, if your App Engine application uses Datastore or Google
> Cloud Storage, a Python client could access those storage resources
> using the Remote API.

in order to get remotely access to Google Cloud Datastore using webapp2.